# Trying to put a Dictionary in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
bank = {'id':{'moneys':{}}}

with open(bankID.txt, 'r') as a:
    for key in a.readlines():
        bank['id']=[str(key)[0:3]]
with open(banknumbers.txt) as b:
    for value in b.readlines():
        bankID = value[0:3]
        bankMoney = int(value[4:9])

        if bank['id'] == bankID:
              bank['id]['money']= bankMoney
        #bank[bankID] = bankMoney  <--this one kinda works but it isnt right.
        #an example of the 2nd txt file would look like
        #234 8763    so id number and money respectively
```

How come my first forloop does not assign all my id with a key. when I print (bank['id']) the only value that comes out is the first key read.
In my first txt file it only has the bank id and the second txt file has the bank id and the amount of money after it. I cant seem to figure out how to compare the bank id of my dictionary and the bank id of the 2nd txt file and assign the value for money.

So I want the output to look like {'875': 234,'576': 345, '676': 8837}

Comment: you keep setting the same key `"id"` to different values, are you trying to store multiple values for the key?

Comment: can you show a bit of your `bankID.txt`?

Comment: Yes for the first one i want multiple keys. For the second, I want Money to be another key that has multiple values. So i can have multiple ids that show all the money they have

Comment: If you add a snippet of both input files it will make life a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

*How come my first forloop does not assign all my id with a key.*

Because you're telling it to assign the key "id" the value [str(key)[0:3]]
So you wind up with exactly one key, the string literal "id" and whatever the last value of [str(key)[0:3]] was.

You don't actually need a dictionary within a dictionary unless you have 3 values to keep track of, like a bankId, transactionId and amount.

Suppose banknumbers.txt looked like this instead:

```
# 234 8763  44.55 -- so a bank number, a transaction number and some money.
```

This would give you a dictionary within a dictionary for that:

```
bank = {}

with open(bankID.txt, 'r') as a:
    for key in a.readlines():
    bank[str(key)[0:3]] = {}
with open(banknumbers.txt) as b:
    for value in b.readlines():
        bankID = value[0:3]
        transactionId = int(value[4:9])
        money = float(value(9:19))
        bank[bankID][transactionId] = money
```

You should probably go read the relevant section of the python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score -1):

I think you're misunderstanding dictionaries. You're overwriting bank['id'] every iteration in the for loop. I'm not exactly sure what you want, but you may want to have a list of banks. The code would be:

```
bank = []

with open(bankID.txt, 'r') as a:
    for key in a.readlines():
        bank.append({'id':[str(key)[0:3]], 'moneys': 0})

with open(banknumbers.txt) as b:
    for value in b.readlines():
        bankID = value[0:3]
        bankMoney = int(value[4:9])

        for bnk in bank:
            if bnk['id'] == bankID:
                bnk['money'] = bankMoney
```